Expo av audio metadata doesn't work on android

According to the expo-av documentation, it's confirmed that setOnMetadataUpdate is not supported on Android. You can find more details at https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#setonmetadataupdateonmetadataupdate.
Is there a workaround available to access metadata on Android? I need to display the song's title and artist. The functionality is working flawlessly on iOS.
